# how to put gap between bootstrap multiple item carousels columns and prev and next buttons

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and  have written a multiple item carousel like this:
[image]

it works well but I can't put a gap between each column or item and I don't want half of the fifth column to be shown.I added padding classes to columns or carousel items but they did not solve my problem. And when I add padding to the carousel it does not add any padding from the left side.

here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12">
<div id="populars" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner w-100 p-5" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active bg-danger mx-2">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 card p-1 " style="line-height:1.2;">
<img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="a.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 card p-1 " style="line-height:1.2;">
<img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="a.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 card p-1 " style="line-height:1.2;">
<img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="a.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 card p-1" style="line-height:1.2;">
<img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="a.jpg">
</div>
</div>

</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#populars" role="button" 
data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#populars" role="button" 
data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="btn btn-danger p-3 p-md-4 mx-auto mt-5 rounded-0">
show menu
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
transform: translateX(100%);
}
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {*
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
}
/* medium - display 2  */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
transform: translateX(50%);
}

#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
}

/* large - display 3 */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
transform: translateX(25%);
}
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
transform: translateX(-25%);
}
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div {
display: none;
}
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div:first-child {
display: block;
}
}
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
display: flex;
}
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
#populars .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you make the width of this element <div id="populars" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel"> narrower and then centre it?

Comment: Do you mean to clean the w-100 class and make the div center align? I added the align-items-center class to the div element containing the carousel but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a gap between your elements you can use the gap property.
I have a similar project and I am using BS4 Carousel and to add space between my cards I use gap.

For example:

HTML

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="slide-box">
                        ....your content here....
```

CSS:

```
.slide-box {
display: flex;
gap: 2rem;
}
```